# Intuit - Getting a 401 - unauthorized error when providing MFA answer for captcha image

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

We're using the Intuit Customer Account Data API to connect to banks in our application. While the credentials and security questions go through fine, we're getting an Unauthorized error when we provide the answer to the security image (captcha image). Providing a blank does not help either. We get this error only when the answer is correct, in the case of incorrect answer the response is "Incorrect MFA answer".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this use-case using CC_Bank( dummy FI setup for testing).

Here is the test username-pwd link for different use cases.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/testing_calls_to_the_api

You should debug the use case using CC_Bank. If it still doesn't work then you should raise a support ticket.

- https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incident

Thanks

Comment: Hi Manas, We tried using the CC bank and it went through fine. We kept getting the same captcha image and whatever we entered went though fine. On the other hand, we got different images for the real financial institutions and even after entering the correct answer, it dint go through.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you to raise a support ticket. 
Someone from IPP support will look into this and respond.

Comment: Okay, i'll do that. Thank you!